# Can jQuery determine which divs are currently in the user's browser view?

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-events

Is it possible to determine which div is currently in the browser's view, and then fire an event when that occurs? Basically, I have a website that has 5-6 sections all on one page and I want to fire events depending on which section is currently in view on the browser. I know we can link directly to positions of a page using the # tag in hrefs, but is this possible to determine which is currently in main view on the browser?

Comment: Well, people have different resolutions and window sizes, so it'll be hard to tell when a certain elements is on view unless you use fixed heights and widths and then try to implement something around the scrollbar size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.
The basic idea behind that is to watch the scrolling and to determine which of your `sections` is focused by the user.
A good guess for this is usually the section, which is next to the top of your viewport:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      scrollTop = $this.scrollTop(),
      // find the section next to the current scroll top
      sections = $(this).find('section'),
      topSection = null,
      minDist = Infinity;

  sections.each(function() {
    // calculate top and bottom offset of the section
    var top = $(this).offset().top,
        bottom = top + $(this).innerHeight(),
        // only use the minimum distance to the scroll top
        relativeDistance = Math.min(
          Math.abs(top - scrollTop), 
          Math.abs(bottom - scrollTop)
        );
    // in case the distance is smaller than
    // the previous one's replace it
    if (relativeDistance < minDist) {
      minDist = relativeDistance;
      topSection = this;
    }
  });

  // flip the 'top' class from current to now next one
  $('section.top').removeClass('top');
  $(topSection).addClass('top');    
});
```

You can see a quite nice example of this at the [Play Webframework's Homepage](http://www.playframework.org/2.0)

If that is not quite what you want, you may observe the full `offset` or `position` of any Element and compare it to the current viewport using `$(window).innerWidth()` or `$(window).innerHeight()`

**UPDATE**
Added a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/alaxuc/edit#javascript,live) to see it in action. Enjoy ;)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for - thanks very much for the reply! Going to try this out now!

Comment: Wow, thanks for taking the time to set up the demo. This is very, very helpful - thanks again!